# How to repair over de-eased dialogue?

Tags: dialogue

I have the following problem. I recorded a dialogue trough my SPL de-esser in a unknown non treated room. On some sibilants the de-esser did too much. The problem is -> I have no budget for another recording. Do you have any advice on how to get rid of that "teethless" sound on the destroyed words?

I used automating the level of the essex but it did not work.

Comment: Massey has a de-esser with a re-ess function, never tried it. They have full functional demo's.

Answer (score 2):

I would try doing some upward expansion with a multiband compressor or active eq (Waves c4 or McDsp AE400). You could also duplicate your dialog track booth the hell out of the sibilant frequency and side chain a compressor that can do upward expansion (Waves Renaissance Compressor) on the original track. Every time your sibilance gets low that frequency should get expanded or boosted.

Answer (score 2):

- find a decent S and paste it in anywhere you're in dire need of one.
- highpass a copy of the track (with a linear phase EQ if you have to) and automate its volume
- upwards expansion on the high band using a multiband compressor.

make yourself some coffee ;)